# No HTTPS on my ubuntu 20.04 after upgrade

Tags: networking, internet, https

For some reason, after the Upgrade to 20.04 LTS, the vm doesn't have any internet anymore. only https though. http works.

`wget http` works

`wget https` doesn't

it's hosted on vSphere, network config is ok too, since http works. i also can't edit any options in the settings app related to network

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

#source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens160
iface ens160 inet static
        address 192.168.100.38
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.100.254
        dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

output of wget https

```
root@hllin8:/home/user# wget https://google.com
--2022-02-28 11:15:23--  https://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 172.217.168.46, 2a00:1450:400a:808::200e
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|172.217.168.46|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|2a00:1450:400a:808::200e|:443... failed: Network is unreachable.
root@hllin8:/home/user#
```

output of `sudo ufw status numbered`

```
root@hllin8:/home/user# sudo ufw status numbered
Status: inactive
```

output `openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 < /dev/null`

```
root@hllin8:/home/user# openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 < /dev/null
140081291314496:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
140081291314496:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
140081291314496:error:02002065:system library:connect:Network is unreachable:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
140081291314496:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=101
```

output of `tracepath -4 google.com`

```
root@hllin8:/home/user# tracepath -4 google.com
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  public ip (censored)                        2.538ms
 1:  public ip (censored)                         1.707ms
 2:  no reply
 3:  46.140.4.125                                         12.009ms
 4:  ch-otf01b-rc2-ae-51-0.aorta.net                      16.933ms asymm  6
 5:  ch-zrh01b-ra1-ae-9-0.aorta.net                       13.183ms
 6:  72.14.221.112                                        11.635ms
 7:  no reply
 8:  no reply
 9:  no reply
10:  no reply
11:  no reply
12:  no reply
13:  no reply
14:  no reply
15:  no reply
16:  no reply
17:  no reply
18:  no reply
19:  no reply
20:  no reply
21:  no reply
22:  no reply
23:  no reply
24:  no reply
25:  no reply
26:  no reply
27:  no reply
28:  no reply
29:  no reply
30:  no reply
     Too many hops: pmtu 1500
     Resume: pmtu 1500
```

Comment: "... only https. http works". Can you please provide more details. e.g. `curl http(s)://www.google.com` or something else?

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text paste all text into the body of the question.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the output of `wget` for https?

Comment: okay... try: `openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 < /dev/null`

Comment: From my perspective it looks like a firewall issue somewhere on the route to Google... a `connection refused` is an typically an ICMP message coming from the firewall filter, we can be sure, that Google does respond to HTTPS requests. Try `tracepath -4 google.com` and check the routers on your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was a firewall issue. firewall was misconfigured and wouldn't let the port 443 through...